# Is it possible to run a Tor middle node on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, node, middle

I have a Windows PC, and I'm wanting to run a middle node on it. The problem is, after a LOT of googling, I see nothing on how to run a middle node on Windows. In fact, on https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/guard/ it shows nothing on how to run a middle node on Windows: [image: In fact, on https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/guard/ it shows nothing on how to run a middle node on Windows]

So, is it even possible to run a middle node on Windows? If so, how?

Comment: Running a relay on Windows is relatively uncommon (today 41 of the 6245 relays run Windows). Many of the steps for setting up your relay will be the same as the other guides, but the most significant difference will be setting up the relay as an always-running Windows service. You can download the Windows Expert Bundle from here: https://www.torproject.org/download/tor/. You might find this helpful: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#NTService. You may also have to add Windows firewall rules to allow incoming connections for the relay. I can't give a guide as I don't use Windows.

Comment: I would also put in, that you can't turn off Window' telemetry back to Microsoft. You can tell it to reduce the amount but you can't turn in off and it's up to you to believe them when they say it is "anonymized".